# Are soaked almonds easier to digest than unsoaked almonds?

Tags: nutrition, cooking

Many people, especially in India, soak almonds overnight before eating them.

Some people claim this has health benefits. For example [MD-Health](http://www.md-health.com/Soaked-Almonds.html) claim:

> when soaked, almonds release enzyme inhibitor that protects the seed till germination.  As a result, it's easier for people to digest the fruit.

[Livestrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/509747-why-do-people-soak-almonds-in-water/) agrees and further claims:

> Softer almonds are easier to digest, which increases the amount of nutrients your body can absorb from the nut.

Are soaked almonds easier to digest than unsoaked almonds?

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I've edited them in and re-opened the question. While MD-Health do make some additional (dubious?) claims about weight-loss and cancer, I avoided them because I think they are referring to all almonds, not just soaked ones.